# prevent magento from importing images that already exist in var/import/images folder

Tags: magento, file-upload

I am using admin csv import feature
In my csv file I have base, small and thumbnail image columns
When I do an import, all image come in fine and can be seen as expected

However, when I do a subsequent import, if the image columns are in that csv doc then I am seeing multiple images in the PDP page

Is there a way to prevent this other than not having the columns in the import file, obviously

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. For that you need to do custom code.

Comment: can you teach magento to ignore special characters and whitespace in image file names